# android pip mode and activity navigation

Tags: android, android-picture-in-picture

I have a media player activity and I enter pip mode.
When video is playing on pip mode, if I navigate to other pages within app say from navigation drawer, other pages(activities) gets loaded on pip mode.  I want to navigate to any pages within app when a video is playing pip mode. Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

build tool version! you can't build app on lower version and run app on higher version os. PIP breaks here.